# How to read files iteratively and get segregated output in R?

Tags: r, csv, average, mean, txt

I have multiple .gz files (1 file for each month and it contains per minute data) stored in multiple folders (1 folder for 1 state). The order of file is as follows:

```
C:/Users/Desktop/Data/Test_OP (i.e., Main folder or wd)
 Ala (i.e. Folder 1)
   Ala_2021-03_0100_JC_qualitya.txt.gz
   Ala_2021-05_0100_JC_qualitya.txt.gz
   Ala_2022-02_0100_JC_qualitya.txt.gz
 
 Chi (i.e. Folder 2)
   TEX_2019-06_0100+0500_JC_qualitya.txt.gz
   TEX_2020-07_0100+0300_JC_qualitya.txt.gz
   ...
   ...
```

I have ungz them to get various .txt files in the respective folders and processed them to get 15-rows mean of all columns. I am using the following code in R to achieve it. But as an output, I am getting one .csv file containing 15rows mean for all the files (i.e., the data of all the files has clubbed together). However, I want the same output in .csv file but in a segregated manner as per the station, as mentioned below. Also, the code that I am using read all files in one go, I want to process the files iteratively through each state. Could anyone please help me in modifying the code to achieve the desired output.

```
Desired output
Ala
Time_sp C1 [C1c] C2 [C2c] C3 [C3c] C4 [C3c] C5 [h]               
2021-03-01 00:00:00+00 257 285 255 .....
2021-03-01 00:15:00+00  .....
2021-03-01 00:30:00+00  .....
..

Chi
Time_sp  C1 [CC]  C2 [C2]  C3 [C2]  C4  C5 [h]
2020-03-01 00:00:00+00  267  215  250 .....
2020-03-01 00:15:00+00  .....
2020-03-01 00:30:00+00  .....
..
```

The code that I am using in R is as follows:

```
setwd("D:/Test2/")

library(data.table)
library(tidyr)

#List of files
filelist <- list.files("D:/Test2/", full.names = TRUE, recursive 
                   = TRUE, pattern = ".txt$")

#Read the files
dt <- lapply(filelist, function(file) {
  lines <- readLines(file)
  comment_end = match("*/", lines)
  fread(file, skip = comment_end)
})

#Adjust Column names
dt.tidied <- lapply(dt, FUN = function(x){
  #adjust ? to degree
  setnames(x, old = "T2 [?C]", new = "T2 [°C]", skip_absent = TRUE)

  colnames(x) <- gsub("\\[", "(", colnames(x))
  colnames(x) <- gsub("\\]", ")", colnames(x))

  if ("C1c" %in% colnames(x)) {
    x[C1c != 0, C := NA]
    x[C < -5 | C > 5, C := NA]
  }

  #return
  return(x)
})

 #bind, filling missing columns to NA
merged <- rbindlist(dt.tidied, fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)

#mn <- merged %>% separate(`Date/Time`, into = c("Date", "Time"), sep = 
 #"T")

cn <- c('Date/Time', 'DIF (W/m**2)', 'DIR (W/m**2)', 'LWD (W/m**2)', 
'LWU (W/m**2)', 'PoPoPoPo (hPa)', 'RH (%)', 'SWD (W/m**2)', 'SWU 
(W/m**2)', 'SumSW (W/m**2)', 'SWDTOA (W/m**2)', 'T2 (°C)')

mnf <- merged[, cn, with = FALSE ] %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  group_by(group = as.integer(gl(n(), 15, n()))) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ if(mean(is.na(.x)) > 0.8) NA else 
mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))) 

mnf

write.csv(mnf, 'D:/Test2/15min_full.csv')
```

The dput() of my sample input data (excluding initial rows) is as follows:

```
The dput() of a sample input txt file (excluding initial rows) is as follows:

structure(list(`Date/Time` = structure(c(1614556800, 1614556860, 
1614556920, 1614556980, 1614557040, 1614557100), tzone = "UTC", class = 
c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), `XY [XY]` = c(0.990641, 0.990641, 0.990641, 
0.990641, 0.990641, 0.990641), `C1 [C1]` = c(257, 257, 257, 256, 255, 
255), Cc = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `C2 [C2]` = c(285, 284, 289, 264, 
231, 223), Dc = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `C3 [C3]` = c(255, 255, 
255, 255, 254, 254), Ac = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), C4 = c(0.463735, 
0.465678, 0.467612, 0.469561, 0.471472, 0.473374), `C5 [h]` = c(1013, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `C6 [%]` = c(43, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `C7 [E2]` = 
c(390, 390, 393, 380, 365, 361), Jc = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `D [S]` = 
c(62.3716, 62.2459, 62.1206, 61.9942, 61.8701, 61.7465), `Sw [S2]` = 
c(1392.95, 1392.95, 1392.95, 1392.95, 1392.95, 1392.95), `SW [Q2]` = 
c(389.164, 389.253, 392.14, 379.964, 363.91, 360.562), `QA [H2]` = 
c(646.61, 649.313, 652.002, 654.712, 657.371, 660.016), `T2 [C]` = 
c(3.7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Lc = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Initial rows are as follows:

```
/* DESCRIPTION:
Alg
Checks: V1.0
Const:  90 W
Const:  4 W
Para(s):DATE/TIME (Date/Time)
XY [XY] (XY)
C1 [CC] (C1)
Cc (Cc)
C2 [C2] (C2)
Dc (Dc)
C3 [C3] (C3)
Ac (Ac)
C4 (C4)
C5 [h] (C5)
C6 [%] (C6)
C7 [E2] (C7)
Jc (Jc)
D [S] (D)
Sw [S2] (Sw)
SW [Q2] (SW)
QA [H2] (QA)
T2 [C] (T2)
Lc (Lc)
*/
```

Comment: Can I suggest you use dput() to show four examples of your input files with minimal data, two files each for two folders, as well as an example of what you want your output to look like based on the example of the four files? With data for a reproducible example and specific file formats it may be easier for people to help you.

Comment: @stomper Hi, I have added dput() of input and my desired output.

Comment: It's quite different question than the orginal. Few notes - if you are happy with how extraction is handled, I'd suggest you to change your starting point to having `*.txt` files, i.e. drop your extraction logic from the question, this would get rid of about half of the code and shifts the focus to your actual question. If handling comments in input files works  for you, consider dropping that part too.

Comment: `dput()` output seems to be manually altered, those added newlines in timestamps have quite a severe impact on how test data will be written to a file and how it gets read back.  I'd rather see actual lines copied from extracted input files. As you are now using `data.tables` and `fread()  , does that `separate(Date/Time, ..) ` actuallywork? `fread()`should parse datetime strings from input files, so there's no string with a "T" anymore  spearating will likely fail (or just generates empty column(s) ).

Comment: @margusl fread() is removing the T but it is not seperating the Date/Time column into two columns. Nor it is creating an empty column.

Comment: @margusl I have removed extraction part from the code and update my existing code.

Comment: @margusl I have added the new output of dput() of input data (including initial rows). I don't know but I am facing problem in formatting, that's why, it doesn't appear in a standard way

Comment: @margusl I have added the new output of dput() of input data and initial rows to be skipped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's quite a different question than the original, here's another take. There are still some contradicting bits in provided data, existing code and desired output, but if the core of this question is how to cycle through directories and get a summary for each of those, the logic is hopefully here.

Tried to keep as close to provided code as possible, but had to adjust according to provided data, also dropped the extraction part. And refactored some blocks into functions.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

#Read the files
read_the_files <- function(filelist){
  lapply(filelist, function(file) {
    # skip rows until fragment from header row is detected 
    fread(file, skip = "Date/Time\tXY")
  })
}

#Adjust Column names
adjust_column_names <- function(dt_list){
  lapply(dt_list, FUN = function(x){
    #adjust ? to degree
    setnames(x, old = "T2 [?C]", new = "T2 [°C]", skip_absent = TRUE)
    
    colnames(x) <- gsub("\\[", "(", colnames(x))
    colnames(x) <- gsub("\\]", ")", colnames(x))
    
    #return
    return(x)
  })
}
# directory with samples generated from provided data
setwd(file.path(tempdir(), "Test_OP"))
fs::dir_tree()
#> .
#> ├── Ala
#> │   ├── 1.txt
#> │   ├── 2.txt
#> │   ├── 3.txt
#> │   ├── 4.txt
#> │   └── 5.txt
#> └── Chi
#>     ├── 1.txt
#>     ├── 2.txt
#>     ├── 3.txt
#>     ├── 4.txt
#>     └── 5.txt


dirlist <- list.files(full.names = FALSE, no.. = TRUE) 
dirlist
#> [1] "Ala" "Chi"

# Cycle trhough directories in current working directory,
# create a summary file for files in each dir
for (idx in seq_along(dirlist)){
  filelist <- list.files(path = dirlist[idx], full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, pattern = ".txt$")
  dt_ <- read_the_files(filelist)
  dt.tidied <- adjust_column_names(dt_)
  
  #bind, filling missing columns to NA
  merged <- rbindlist(dt.tidied, fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)
  # fread() should have parsed datetime strings, so at that point separate() should just
  # rename `Date/Time` to Date and create Time filled with NAs
  # mn <- merged %>% separate(`Date/Time`, into = c("Date", "Time"), sep = "T")

  # Create 15 minute groups with lubridate, summarise only numeric columns
  mnf <- merged %>% 
    as_tibble() %>%
    group_by(Time_sp = lubridate::floor_date(`Date/Time`, "15 mins")) %>% 
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ if(mean(is.na(.x)) > 0.8) NA else mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
  write.csv(mnf, paste0(dirlist[idx],"_15min_full.csv"), row.names = FALSE)
}
```

```r
# Last processed directory:
dirlist[idx]
#> [1] "Chi"
# Last generated summary dataframe:
mnf
#> # A tibble: 3 × 19
#>   Time_sp             `XY (XY)` `C1 (CC)`    Cc `C2 (C2)`    Dc `C3 (C2)`    Ac
#>   <dttm>                  <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 2021-03-01 00:00:00     0.991       257     0       285     0       255     0
#> 2 2021-03-01 00:15:00     0.991       257     0       285     0       255     0
#> 3 2021-03-01 00:30:00     0.991       257     0       285     0       255     0
#> # ℹ 11 more variables: C4 <dbl>, `C5 (h)` <dbl>, `C6 (%)` <dbl>,
#> #   `C7 (E2)` <dbl>, Jc <dbl>, `D (S)` <dbl>, `Sw (S2)` <dbl>, `SW (Q2)` <dbl>,
#> #   `OA (H2)` <dbl>, `T2 (C)` <dbl>, Lc <dbl>

# Files in working directory:
fs::dir_info()[1:3] 
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   path               type             size
#>   <fs::path>         <fct>     <fs::bytes>
#> 1 Ala                directory           0
#> 2 Ala_15min_full.csv file              480
#> 3 Chi                directory           0
#> 4 Chi_15min_full.csv file              480
```

Reprex setup:

```r
# reprex setup ------------------------------------------------------------
library(fs)
library(purrr)

# Sample is crafted by combining 
# https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76255679/9 and
# https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76334740/6 
# Includes some manual changes so may or may not apply

file_sample <-  c(
  "/* DESCRIPTION:",
  "Algo:\tSolp", 
  "Checks:\tV2.0",
  "Const:\t89 W", 
  "Const1:\t9 W",
  "Para(s):\tDATE/TIME (Date/Time)", 
  "\tXY [XY] (XY)",
  "\tC1 [C1] (C1)", "\tCc (Cc)",
  "\tC2 [C2] (C2)", "\tAc (Ac)",
  "\tC3 [C3] (C3)", "\tDc (Dc)",
  "\tC4 (C4)", 
  "\tC5 [h] (h)","\tC6DH [%] (C6DH)", 
  "\tC7 [E2] (C7)","\tJc (Jc)","\tD [S] (D)", "\tSw [S2] (Sw)",
  "\tSW [Q2] (SW)", "\tQA [H2] (QA)","\tT2 [C] (T2)", "\tLc (Lc)",
  "*/", 
  "Date/Time\tXY [XY]\tC1 [C1]\tCc\tC2 [C2]\tAc\tC3 [C3]\tDc\tC4\tC5 [h]\tC6DH [%]\tC7 [E2]\tJc\tS [D]\tSw [S2]\tQ2 [SW]\tQA [H2]\tT2 [C]\tLc",
  "2021-03-01T00:00:00\t0.990641\t257\t0\t285\t0\t255\t0\t0.463735\t1013\t43\t390\t0 \t62.3716\t1392.95\t389.164\t646.61\t3.7\t0",
  "2021-03-01T00:01:00\t0.990641\t257\t0\t284\t0\t255\t0\t0.465678\t\t\t390\t0\t62.2 459\t1392.95\t389.253\t649.313\t\t0",
  "2021-03-01T00:02:00\t0.990641\t257\t0\t289\t0\t255\t0\t0.467612\t\t\t393\t0\t62.1 206\t1392.95\t392.14\t652.002\t\t0"
)

main_d <- path(tempdir(), "Test_OP")
walk(path(main_d, c("Ala/", "Chi/")), dir_create)
paste0(c("Ala/", "Chi/"), rep(1:5, each =2), ".txt") %>% 
  walk(\(fname) writeLines(file_sample, path(main_d, fname)))
dir_tree(main_d)
#> Temp/RtmpEdFDdc/Test_OP
#> ├── Ala
#> │   ├── 1.txt
#> │   ├── 2.txt
#> │   ├── 3.txt
#> │   ├── 4.txt
#> │   └── 5.txt
#> └── Chi
#>     ├── 1.txt
#>     ├── 2.txt
#>     ├── 3.txt
#>     ├── 4.txt
#>     └── 5.txt

# file content:
readLines(path(main_d, "Ala/1.txt")) %>% paste0(collapse = "\n") %>% cat()
#> /* DESCRIPTION:
#> Algo:    Solp
#> Checks:  V2.0
#> Const:   89 W
#> Const1:  9 W
#> Para(s): DATE/TIME (Date/Time)
#>  XY [XY] (XY)
#>  C1 [C1] (C1)
#>  Cc (Cc)
#>  C2 [C2] (C2)
#>  Ac (Ac)
#>  C3 [C3] (C3)
#>  Dc (Dc)
#>  C4 (C4)
#>  C5 [h] (h)
#>  C6DH [%] (C6DH)
#>  C7 [E2] (C7)
#>  Jc (Jc)
#>  D [S] (D)
#>  Sw [S2] (Sw)
#>  SW [Q2] (SW)
#>  QA [H2] (QA)
#>  T2 [C] (T2)
#>  Lc (Lc)
#> */
#> Date/Time    XY [XY] C1 [C1] Cc  C2 [C2] Ac  C3 [C3] Dc  C4  C5 [h]  C6DH [%]    C7 [E2] Jc  S [D]   Sw [S2] Q2 [SW] QA [H2] T2 [C]  Lc
#> 2021-03-01T00:00:00  0.990641    257 0   285 0   255 0   0.463735    1013    43  390 0   62.3716 1392.95 389.164 646.61  3.7 0
#> 2021-03-01T00:01:00  0.990641    257 0   284 0   255 0   0.465678            390 0   62.2 459    1392.95 389.253 649.313     0
#> 2021-03-01T00:02:00  0.990641    257 0   289 0   255 0   0.467612            393 0   62.1 206    1392.95 392.14  652.002     0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for revising the code. Your code is giving me following error. Error in `group_by()`:
ℹ In argument: `Time_sp = lubridate::floor_date(`Date/Time`, "15 mins")`.
Caused by error in `lubridate::floor_date()`:
! object 'Date/Time' not found. Can you please help in resolving it.

Comment: Hi, I am still receiving the same error. But lately, I tested the same code with few sample files without initial rows (which are present in my data and I want to skip them) and your code worked successfully with that data. So, I think probably, the issue is that it is not skipping the initial rows and because of which it is not able to read the 'Date/Time' column from the files which have initial rows. Could you please help me in resolving it.

Comment: Hi, I have checked the dput(head(merged)) and it shows the initial rows of my data which I want to skip. I am doing that in #Read the files in my code. I am not sure if fread() is doing the same or which part in your code is skipping the initial rows. That's why, may be it is not able to find the Date/Time column. Can you please help me with this. I am really stuck.

Comment: My code did not skip **any** initial rows as at that time there was nothing to test against, hence the ``## can't test comments ##`  remark before commented out line in reading block.  Try including `skip = "Date/Time\tXY"` in `fread()` to skip anything before column header line.